# Sourcing “torsocks on” in fish and dash shells

Tags: linux, torsocks

I have used `torify` for a while to ad hoc route the traffic of certain applications through Tor and just today noticed that the man page suggests using `torsocks` instead. Reading through the `torsocks(1)` man page I see the ability to do `torsocks on` and `torsocks off` to “encapsulate” a larger section of commands instead of having to preface each individual call with `torsocks` (or `torify`).

However. The given `. torsocks on|off` (or using `source` instead of the shorthand `.`) is not working in `dash` or in `fish` and seems to be relying on behaviour that appears to be specific to `bash` and `zsh` (though I didn’t test in other shells than these four).

I’ve used this simple script to test it with the various shells, changing the first line to whichever shell I was trying:

```
#!/usr/bin/dash
source torsocks on
torsocks show
```

Is there a way to source `torsocks on|off` in a shell that doesn’t do whatever it is bash/zsh is doing here?

Answer (score 0):

Fish and Dash are specifically tailored shells, so quite a lot of functionality is trimmed or removed there. Just use a regular bash - this is **that** simple. In case of the embedded platform - where you're short in resources - just compile a C/C++ code to do so and save even more resources fulfilling the task, that's it